# Инкапсуляция кота

Tags: java, ооп, инкапсуляция, setter

> Спроектируйте класс Cat с любыми полями, но таким образом, чтобы для него были доступны следующие методы:
>
> **setName(String name)** - дать имя коту
>
> **getName()** - получить имя кота
>
> **run()** - бежать, уменьшает уровень энергии на 100
>
> **getStamina()** - возвращает текущий уровень энергии. Стартовая энергия кота - 1000.
>
> **eat()** - увеличивает уровень энергии на 200
>
> **sleep()** - увеличивает уровень энергии на 100

Поскольку в ООП я полнейший ноль пока, то написал разумеется что-то корявое, что не работает. Подскажите, как и что поправить, чтоб было правильно.

```
    class Cat {
private String name;
private int run, eat, sleep;
private int Stamina = 1000;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
    public void ustalost (int run){
    Stamina =  Stamina - 100;
}
public void naelsya (int eat){
    Stamina = Stamina + 200;
}
public void  spit (int sleep){
    Stamina = Stamina + 100;
}
public int getStamina() {
    return Stamina;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ох уж эти "не работает" из серии "я ничего не трогала, оно само сломалось". Почему вы считаете, что не работает? Как по вашему должно быть на самом деле (какой хотите получить результат)

Comment: Результат нужен такой, чтоб в Main все работало. А пока же он выдает такие вот ошибки:Compilation error
Main.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cat.run();
                                       ^
  symbol:   method run()
  location: variable cat of type Cat
Main.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        cat.eat();
           ^
  symbol:   method eat()
  location: variable cat of type Cat
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        cat.sleep();
           ^
  symbol:   method sleep()
  location: variable cat of type Cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас все сказанно в ошибке:

```
Compilation error Main.java
  cannot find symbol cat.run();
  cannot find symbol cat.eat();
  cannot find symbol cat.sleep();
```

У вас некорректно описаны эти методы, не так как указанно в задании, из-за чего внешний код выполняющий проверку вашего класса не может скомпилироватся.

Вместо методов `run()`, `eat()`, `sleep()` вы по ошибке указали `ustalost (int run)`, `naelsya (int eat)`, `spit (int sleep)` - просто переименуйте их так, как указанно в задании, да уберите параметры(они здесь не нужны) - код успешно соберется.

В остальном - все ок.

Comment: Все именно так, а я уж и Main написал чтоб проверить и найти ошибку, а тут все гораздо проще оказалось) Спасибо!